# How to filter date dynamically in MongoDB extended JSON

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

Need to fetch greater than today date data using MongoDB Java driver. I am using MongoDB Extended JSON and not sure how to pass the current date in Query.

**Below is passed with actual value:**
{endDate:{$gt:{$date:“2020-07-08T00:00:00.000Z”}}

I need to pass the dynamic current date instaed of hardcoding the date as below:
{endDate:{$gt:{$date:<today_date>}}

Please help how to achieve this.

Comment: You do not pass extended json to the driver for queries. Use a native date/datetime/timestamp object as documented in driver documentation.